# Why SanDisk Cruzer Glide 8GB can't be made bootable by StartupDiskCreator?

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, usb

I am trying to setup some USB drives to boot Ubuntu 14.04.4 or 15.10 from on my VAIO (Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6500 @ 2.10GHz × 2) using the Startup Disk Creator utility.  After copying files from the .iso onto the USB drive, the utility gives me "System Policy prevents installing the bootloader" and wants authentication to override.  After I supply my password for authentication, it tells me that it could not write the bootloader.  The USB drive is not bootable, but is mountable and has what appears to be a boot drive on it.  The BIOS doesn't see the USB drive as bootable, which makes sense.  What's the problem?

Comment: Try `mkusb`. You may need to 'wipe' your USB stick. The wiki for `mkusb` has details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use universal usb installer , Saves a lot of headache...

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/